# Populate column and add auto number based from other columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just stuck with my project to populate the column `A` based on a value from column `B`. How to populate the column `B` with the value from column `A` and add 3 digit number automatically based from count number of specific value on column `A`?

[image]

Comment: Instead of pictures, please add your data either in text format, or insert clauses, so people trying to help you can test it.

Answer (score 1):

hopefully, you won't have more then 999 counts of A

```
UPDATE T
SET    B = A + RIGHT('000' + convert(varchar(3), rn), 3)
FROM   
(
    SELECT A, B, rn = row_number() over (partition by A order by A)
    FROM   yourtable
) T
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it doesn't work and I want to populate the column B based on value on column A, so if the value on column A is INT12345 then column B would be INT12345001 for first row and for the second row would be INT12345002 etc. but if on the row 3 on columns A is INT5234 then column B would be INT5234001 on the first, any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: @TediSuprapto Instead of saying "It does not work" you should tell what is wrong.

Comment: @TediSuprapto, you mean you have tried the query and it is not giving the required result ?

Comment: Sorry I do something wrong at the first and the query that you made is working and pretty good very helpful for me, I very appreciated with your help Squirrel, two thumb for you... cheers :)